# pig script fails when macro is used twice

Tags: macros, apache-pig, bigdata

I have a pig script that uses a macro twice, on the same relation but with different parameters; for each use I filter the same relation on a different field. Macro is shaped more or as as follows:

```
DEFINE doubleGroupJoin (mainField, mainRelation) returns out {
    valid = FILTER $mainRelation BY $mainField != '';
    r1 = FOREACH (GROUP valid BY $mainField) GENERATE 
            field1_1, field1_2, ...;
    r2 = FOREACH (GROUP valid BY ($mainField, otherfield1, ...) GENERATE
            field2_1, field2_2, ...;
    $out = FOREACH (JOIN R1 BY field1_1, R2 BY field1_2) GENERATE
            final1, final2, ...; 
}
```

In the script I have the following:

```
-- Output1
finalR1 = doubleGroupJoin('field1', initialData);
STORE finalR1 INTO '$output/R1';
-- Output2
finalR2 = doubleGroupJoin('field2', initialData);
STORE finalR2 INTO '$output/R2';
```

If I comment out either Output1 or Output2 blocks, the job works fine, but if I try to use both I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.BinSedesTuple cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.HDataType.getWritableComparableTypes(HDataType.java:106)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Map.collect(PigGenericMapReduce.java:111)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.runPipeline(PigGenericMapBase.java:284)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:277)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
```

Using Pig 0.12.0 here. Any suggestion on why this might be happening?

Comment: Further investigation leads to the conclusion that the problem seems to be in the `JOIN` bit of the code, although I've not been able to determine why

Comment: I've been able to get around the issue using the `-no_multiquery` option from command line, although I'm still not sure about the origin of the problem

Comment: you could check with the `-dryrun` option to see what is generated. Looks strange though